# Material component persian datepicker in angular 2

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular5, persian

Angular2 Material Component has a DatePicker that shows the date in the default format.

And only support change local to "fa-IR".

How can I format it to show Persian Date?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following steps should help:

**1**: load all required modules in module.ts:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS,MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
```

**2**: install jalali-moment using NPM:

```
 npm install jalali-moment
```

**3**: import jalali date in your app:

```
import * as moment from 'jalali-moment';
```

If you use system.js, you must declare it in system.config.js to run app

**4**: write a custom class to override default date format mechanism

```
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  constructor(matDateLocale: string) {
    super(matDateLocale, new Platform());
  }
  format(date: Date, displayFormat: object): string {
    var faDate = moment(date.toDateString()).locale('fa').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    return faDate;
  }
}
```

**5**: write a constant defining you custom date format

```
const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'input',
    monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' }
  }
}
```

**6**: `MatDatepickerModule` must be added to your `@NgModule`.  Edit your providers section in `@NgModule` to introduce the added class to your app:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fa-IR' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS }
  ],
})
```

**7**: Add the date picker to your html page:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #dateInput matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="date" (change)="dateChange($event,dateInput,picker)" placeholder="انتخاب تاریخ">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**8:** Also to datepicker pop up show date correctly when user change date input handly you must add below code and method to ts file that you put your datepicker control to its html file or template

add below method to handle input change event

```
 public dateChange(event: any, dateInput: any,picker:any) {
    var faDate = dateInput.value;
    moment.locale('fa');
    var enDateMomentFormat  = moment(faDate).locale('en');
    var enDate = new Date(enDateMomentFormat.toLocaleString());
    picker._validSelected = enDate;
    picker.startAt = enDate;
}
```

as date displayed by datepicker had problem, i forced to edit material.umd.js to corrected it.
in address: node_modules/@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js
in line :10947 <==> also you can search for  "MatMonthView.prototype._createWeekCells ="
edit end lines of function as below

```
let displayValue = ariaLabel.split('/')[2];
this._weeks[this._weeks.length - 1]
    .push(new MatCalendarCell(i + 1, Number(displayValue), ariaLabel, enabled));
```

Comment: Where is the Platform() imported from?

Comment: Shows months incorrectly. Month begins from 15! If I pick a day it may change the month!

Comment: it is better to use jalaliDay instead of jalali-moment

Answer (score 1):

Follow below to steps to show Iranian Calendar:

1. Download from npm: `npm install ng2-jalali-date-picker --save`
2. import the DpDatePickerModule module in typescript (.ts) or es6 files like below:
   `import {DpDatePickerModule} from 'ng2-jalali-date-picker';
   Add DpDatePickerModule to your module imports:`
3. Add DpDatePickerModule to your module imports:
   `@NgModule({
          ...
          imports: [
            ...
            DpDatePickerModule
          ]
        })`

How to use

```
`<dp-date-picker 
   dir="rtl"
   [(ngModel)]="dateObject"
   mode="day"
   placeholder="تاریخ"
   theme="dp-material">
 </dp-date-picker>`
```

`dateObject = "";
 //OR if you have initial value you could use following code
 import * as moment from 'jalali-moment';
 dateObject = moment('1395-11-22','jYYYY,jMM,jDD');`

Refer following libraries for your reference:
[jalali-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-jalali-date-picker) , [persiandatepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/persiandatepicker)

Comment: how can i use this picker for select time

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `jalali-moment`. [Check the bundle size](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=jalali-moment@3.3.8). Also it's not tree-shakable.

Instead I've written my own `MaterialJalaliDateAdapter` based on [ng-bootstrap jalali](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/1f466edaa222812a15d233ab6a604ece68e3a58b/src/datepicker/jalali/jalali.ts) and by replacing it with the `jalali-moment` from [this repo](https://github.com/gembbot/persian-material6-date-picker/blob/master/material.persian-date.adapter.ts). The result code is big and is available in [this repo](https://gist.github.com/gvmohzibat/54098fa3146067b8d1967d3d72fe8ac8).

You can use it like this:

```
{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MaterialJalaliDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS },
```