# Angular material 2 jalali datepicker

Tags: datepicker, angular-material2

I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48582250/4140302) for Persian date-picker But the calendar has problem.

1. days start from 12 in all months.
2. Esfand of 1396 has not 10 and 11 days!
   [image: Sample]