# change angular-material2 datetime picker to jalali

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, angular-material2

i have used `{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fa-IR' }` in app module to change datetimepicker to shamsi(jalali) datetimepicker, But it's wrong to set days and weeks on the page like pick in app,Similar attached photo[image]

As you can see, the first day of the month starts at number 12

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581641/material-component-persian-datepicker-in-angular-2

Comment: I do exactly the same, but I have a problem